# Thoughtworks Go - unable to clean working directory

Tags: thoughtworks-go

I'm just trialling Thoughtworks go but it does not work. It cannot clean the work directory and gives me no indication why.

```
Clean working directory is set to true. Unable to clean working directory for agent: /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a shell open on the build agent and it is sitting in the directory you are trying to clean, you will also get an error like this. I accidentally do this all the time when troubleshooting.

Comment: I've faced this issue today. What's the resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like an issue with permissions on the Go agent. I'd verify that the agent directory and all of the files in it are owned by the user it runs as (probably also named Go depending on your operating system).

It may also be helpful to post your question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/go-cd